# Jquery position is not giving expected result

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am upgrading Jquery version from `jquery-1.6.4.min.js` to `jquery-1.10.2.js`

and jquery ui version from `jquery-ui-1.7.2.j`s to `jquery-ui-1.10.3.js`

I have included latest version jquery-ui.css also.

This is script tag i am using.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
```

and this way i am opening a dialog.

```
dialog = $('#dialog-modal-error');
dialog.html (l_str);
dialog.dialog(); /* if i am not using this then it is giving me this error msg.  cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'*/
if (dialog.dialog ('option', 'disabled') == undefined) {
    dialog.dialog (
        {
            autoOpen: true,
            position : { my: 'center', at: 'center'},
            modal : false,
            bgiframe : true,
            buttons: {},
            close : minimizeMessages,
            resizable : false,
            draggable : false
        }

    );


} else {
    dialog.dialog ('open');

}
```

as a result it is always opening my dialog at the right bottom of the page so just want to know why it is showing me this behavior.

I have already checked all the css it is not taking any inherited css.

**Edit:**

I used this also `position : { my: 'center', at: 'center', collison: 'none'}` but not working.

With the last version of jquery it is working fine.

**NOTE: Dialog is always coming out of the screen(Left -Bottom)**

Answer (score 0):

Check out the jQuery UI docs (http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position) it seems that you have left the `of` attribute out. The default value for `position` is `{ my: "center", at: "center", of: window }`. So try specifying the `of: window` attribute.

Comment: I have already checked the same but this is also not resulting me expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'of' attribute to position it properly. Where would you like it positioned?

For example:

```
position:{ my: "center", at: "center", of: $("#aDiv")}
```

This can also be read as:
place the center of my dialog box, at the center of the div with the ID aDiv.